# Am I doing this recursively or would this be considered iteration?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public T get(int i) {

    if(i == 0 ){
        T val = cur.getData();
        cur = head;
        return val;
    }
    else{
        cur = cur.getNext();
        return get(i-1);
    }

}
```

// I have to solve this recursively and I cant use iteration, is this using iteration

Comment: call to itself with a break condition **if (i == 0)** is recursive.

Comment: If you knew what recursion was, you would not have to ask this question.  You seem to be asking "what is recusion?".

Answer (score 3):

> Am I doing this recursively or would this be considered iteration?

Your function is calling itself:

```
public T get(int i) {

    if(i == 0 ){
        T val = cur.getData();
        cur = head;
        return val;
    }
    else{
        cur = cur.getNext();
        return get(i-1); // <============ Here
    }

}
```

By definition, that's recursion, not iteration.

*Iteration* would look something like this:

```
public T get(int i) {
    T val = cur.getData();
    while (i-- > 0) {
        cur = cur.getNext();
        val = cur.getData();
    }
    cur = head;
    return val;
}
```

There, we just loop within `get`, we don't have it call itself. It's not a perfect translation of your recursive example, because it handles things a bit differently if `i` is negative to start with, but it probably meets the intent (both versions could probably use some kind of guard to protect against `i` being negative to start with).